# MySQL - Sum Table 2 Column value(s) showing all Table 1 Descriptions

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables for Transactions and Categories respectively.
I am trying to write a query that will give me results shown in the Query table below.

I have tried the following

```
SELECT IFNULL(categories.Name,'Total') AS category,
       IFNULL(SUM( transactions.Amount),0) AS amount,
       categories.Color 
FROM transactions,categories 
WHERE categories.CatID = transactions.CatID 
GROUP BY  categories.Name WITH ROLLUP
```

This is however not giving me Category B. I would like my Category B to be shown with a Zero - 0 total as below. Please help..

Transactions

```
+-----------+------------+------------+--------+
| TransID   |  SaleDate  | CatID      | Amount |
+-----------+------------+------------+--------+
|         1 | 2012-02-10 | 1          |     10 |
|         2 | 2012-02-10 | 3          |     10 |
|         3 | 2012-02-10 | 3          |     20 |
|         4 | 2012-02-10 | 1          |     25 |
|         5 | 2012-02-10 | 1          |     35 |
|         6 | 2012-02-10 | 3          |      5 |
|         7 | 2012-02-10 | 3          |      5 |
+-----------+------------+------------+--------+
```

Categories

```
+------------+------+----------+
| CatID      | Name | Color    | 
+------------+------+----------+
|          1 |   A  |    Green |
|          2 |   B  |    Red   |
|          3 |   C  |    Blue  |
+------------+------+----------+
```

GETTING RESULT BELOW

```
+-----------+----------------+------------+
| Category  |  Amount        | Color      |
+-----------+----------------+------------+
|         A | 70             | Green      |
|         B | 40             | Blue       |
|     Total | 110            | Blue       |
+-----------+----------------+------------+
```

#

REQUIRED RESULT

```
+-----------+----------------+------------+
| Category  |  Amount        | Color      |
+-----------+----------------+------------+
|         A | 70             | Green      |
|         B | 0              | Red        |
|         C | 40             | Blue       |
|     Total | 110            | Pink       |
+-----------+----------------+------------+
```

Comment: [This article](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) uses venn diagrams to fairly effectively explain join types using the ANSI 92 standard instead of the ANSI 89 standard you're using above.  In your case an outer join is needed to retain records not in both datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a `left join` with `rollup`:

```
select coalesce(c.category, 'total') as category,
       coalesce(sum(t.amount), 0) as amount,
       coalesce(c.color, 'pink') as color -- this is weird
from categories c left join
     transactions t
     on c.catid = t.catid
group by c.category with rollup;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. You're the Man!! - If I may ask how do I write the queryto show Transaction in a date range for column SaleDate in my transactions table.

Comment: @IshmaelChibvuri . . . You would add conditions on the `transactions` to the `on` clause.